# How to use parameters with Oracle JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am using Oracles JDBC driver for 11g. And I want to establish the connection using the parameter defaultRowPrefetch=10000. When I try to call the connection URL, I get the following error:

```
Error trying to connect to 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@atukwos57:1521/LIVE;defaultRowPrefetch=10000':Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

I cant find any examples. Am I using it wrong? Leaving out the parameter establishes the connection.

[image]

Comment: Instead of providing a screenshot of text, you should add the text itself (formatted for readability). Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question.

Comment: Also, don't forget to take the [tour] & read [ask] - and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: The error text suggest there coud be some *DIY* validation in the client - it is neither Java Exception nor `ORA-`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@atukwos57:1521/LIVE?defaultRowPrefetch=10000
```

Syntax

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@[[protocol:]//]
    host1[,host12,host13][:port1][,host2:port2]/service_name[:server][/instance_name]
    [?[parameter-name1=parameter-value1][&parameter-name2=parameter-value2],...]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I receive the same error.

Comment: in which tool are you using jdbc thin ? and which version of jdbc are you using ?

Comment: It is a tool coded in Java. I tried with OJDBC8 and 11.

Comment: so if the jdbc is inside a java code, are you using properties ?

Comment: No. In that tool I have the option to load jar-Files. I am doing so with the OJDBC driver so its classes are loaded. And then I configure the connection string.

Comment: just a question, is it `LIVE` the service name in the database ? It is really strange, that syntax has worked always for me, for any parameter allowed in the thin method

Comment: @BlindSpectator who is raising the error messsage?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Yes, LIVE is the service name.

Comment: I really believe that your issue has nothing to do with the syntax in jdbc thin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called `oracle.jdbc\defaultConnectionProperties.properties` in the jar-file. Adding `oracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch=10000` to this file solved the issue.

Comment: You need not change this in the jar file. You can try to set this as a connection property or a system property. Refer to the sample DataSourceSample.java (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/688d777897bfd9848446253882ba6341d1eabc6c/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) and also refer to OracleConnection.java (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html) for more connection properties.